# Get names in a directory in order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a directory with pictures that have names like this:
v1-001.png
v1-002.png
.....
I want of list the names in order (V1--001 V1-002 V1--003 V1--004) but I have this
v1--00900
v1--002
v1--0034
V1--0020
V1--001

this is my code:

```
import os
path="."

 for current_dir, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in file_names:
        in_file = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
        print(in_file)
```

Comment: What does the code give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply sort the file name list with `sorted()`:

```
for current_dir, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in sorted(file_names):
        in_file = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
        print(in_file)
```